# Send data to serial port when data is available

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized

I'm building an interactive LED table with a 14x14 matrix consisting of addressable LED strips for an university assignment. Those are being controlled by 2 arduinos that get the data about which LED should have which RGB value from a Pi running a server that runs several games which should be playable on the LED table. To control the games I send respective int codes from an android app to the server running on the Raspi.

The serial communication is realized by using jSerialComm. The problem I'm facing is, that I don't want to permanently send data over the serial port but only at the moment, when a new array that specifies the matrix is available.

Therefore I don't want to be busy waiting and permanently checking if the matrix got updated not do I want to check for a update with

```
    while(!matrixUpdated) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
```

So what I've been trying was running a while(true) in which I call wait(), so the thread stops until I wake the thread up by calling notify when an updated matrix is available.

My run() method in the serial thread looks like this at the moment:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    arduino1.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);
    arduino2.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_SCANNER, 0, 0);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    PrintWriter outToArduino1 = new PrintWriter(arduino1.getOutputStream());
    PrintWriter outToArduino2 = new PrintWriter(arduino2.getOutputStream());

    while(true) {

        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

        System.out.println("Matrix received");

        outToArduino1.print(matrix);
        outToArduino2.print(matrix);
    }
}
```

I wake the thread up by this method which is nested in the same class:

```
public void setMatrix(int[][][] pixelIdentifier) {
    matrix = pixelIdentifier;
    notify();
}
```

I also tried notifyAll() which didn't change the outcome.

In one of the games (Tic Tac Toe) I call this method after every game turn to update and send the matrix to the arduinos:

```
private void promptToMatrix() {
    synchronized (GameCenter.serialConnection) {
        GameCenter.serialConnection.setMatrix(matrix);
    }
}
```

I previously called it without using the synchronized block but as I've been reading through many articles on that topic on StackOverflow I have read that one should use synchronized for this. Further I have also read that using wait() and notify() is not recommended, however as the assignment needs to get done quite quickly I don't know if any other approach makes sense as I don't want to restructure my whole application as I run up to 5 threads when a game is being played (due to threads for communication and so on).

If there is a possibility to solve this using wait() and notify() I would be really grateful to hear how that would be done, as I have not been able to really comprehend how working properly with the synchronized block is being done and so on.
However if such a solution is not possible or would also end in restructuring the whole application I'm also open to different suggestions. Pointing out that using wait() and notify() is not recommended however doesn't help me, as I've already read that often enough, I'm aware of that but prefer to use it in that case if possible!!!

**EDIT:**

```
The application executes like this: 
Main Thread
|--> SerialCommunication Thread --> waiting for updated data
|--> NetworkController Thread
     |--> Client Thread --> interacting with the game thread
          |--> Game Thread --> sending updated data to the waiting SerialCommunication Thread
```

Really appreciate any help and thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with asynchronous update possibly running on different threads, the best match in my opinion is using [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

You could use a `Subject` to receive matrix event and then subscribe to it to update the leds.

You can write something like this (don't take it too literally).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] initialValue = new int[32][32];

        BehaviorSubject<int[][]> matrixSubject = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(initialValue);

        SerialPort arduino1 = initSerial("COM1");
        SerialPort arduino2 = initSerial("COM2");;

        PrintWriter outToArduino1 = new PrintWriter(arduino1.getOutputStream());
        PrintWriter outToArduino2 = new PrintWriter(arduino2.getOutputStream());

        Observable<String> serializedMatrix = matrixSubject.map(Sample::toChars);

        serializedMatrix.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(mat -> {
            // Will run on a newly created thread  
            outToArduino1.println(mat);
        });

        serializedMatrix.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(mat -> {
            // Will run on a newly created thread 
            outToArduino2.println(mat);
        });

        // Wait forever
        while(true) {
            try {
                // get your matrix somehow ...
                // then publish it on your subject
                // your subscribers will receive the data and use it.
                matrixSubject.onNext(matrix);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // SWALLOW error
            }
        }

    }

    public static String toChars(int[][] data) {
        // Serialize data
        return null;
    }
```

There are may operators that you could use to make it do what you need, also you can use different schedulers to choose from different thread policies.

You can also transform your input in the subject you publish, an observable or a subject can be created directly from your input.

Comment: I don't exactly know if it's an asynchronous waiting.
In detail my application executes like this:

Main Thread starts a thread for the serial communication and a new NetworkController thread that waits for a client to connect. As soon as the client connects a new ClientThread is started which waits for user input by the client and depending on the input either starts or ends a game thread or accesses the game controls. The games update the data sent over the serial thread after every turn.

Comment: I would still give a look at RXJava which could solve many of those problems in neat way. It does abstract most of the problems , in particular the wait.